# PHP: add hyphen anytime a string contains a number after one letter or more

Tags: php

In my DB i have items names that can be input by users either in the form of Apple MM1 or Banana B-234 or Carl Mm345 (I can't really control too much what users input)

I'd like to be able to convert `Carl Mm345` and convert it in `Carl MM-345` by using PHP: basically adding a dash or hyphen and uppercase all the letter before dash

Comment: Craft yourself a regex and use with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: As far as I know, plain preg_replace can't capitalize letters so for your purpose it is better to look at [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function. I will provide a detailed solution if you specify result for such strings as 'a5b6c7'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert_input($string) {
    $arr = explode(' ', $string);
    if (count($arr) == 1) {
        $first = '';
        $second = strtoupper($string);
    } else {
        $first = $arr[0].' ';
        $second = strtoupper($arr[1]);
    }
    $second = str_replace('-', '', $second);
    $p = strcspn($second, '0123456789');
    $letters = substr($second, 0, $p);
    $numbers = substr($second, $p);
    $glue = $letters && $numbers ? '-' : '';
    return $first.$letters.$glue.$numbers;
}

echo convert_input('mm234');
echo convert_input('Carl Mm345');
echo convert_input('adsf mmmm');
echo convert_input('adsf');
echo convert_input('adsfdsf 123');
echo convert_input('Banana B-234');
```

Comment: so the input can be of the form `abc abd123`, `abc abd-123`, `abd-123` and `abd123`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, and it's probably more efficient to create a `regex` expression, but this PHP function seems to accomplish what you want. I generalized the rules you gave in the question (also note that `strtoupper` makes no difference if the number is upper-cased)

```
function convert($string) {
    $tmp = explode(' ', $string);
    $t = '';
    $var = str_split($tmp[1]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {
        if (is_numeric($var[$i])) {
            $t .= '-';
        }
        $t .= strtoupper($var[$i]);
    }
    return implode('', array($tmp[0])) . $t;
}
```